# Send transactional email with SendGrid on a Rails app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, sendgrid, sendgrid-templates

I am trying to send a transactional email using Sendgrid upon client booking on a Rails application.

I did create a dynamic template as required.
When I make a POST request to https://api.sendgrid.com/v3/mail/send with POSTMAN using the right body and my Sendgrid API key, it works, I do receive the confirmation email.

However, I am a Rails newbie and I really don't know how to proceed with the piece of code provided in the docs:

```
require 'sendgrid-ruby'
include SendGrid

sg = SendGrid::API.new(api_key: ENV['SENDGRID_API_KEY'], impersonate_subuser: The subuser's username. This header generates the API call as if the subuser account was making the call.)
data = JSON.parse('{
  "name": "example_name",
  "generation": "dynamic"
}')

response = sg.client.templates.post(request_body: data)
puts response.status_code
puts response.headers
puts response.body
```

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: 1. you dont need `include Sendgrid`. NEVER EVER use `include` on a global level (not within a class or module.
2. just put that stuff into an action in a controller and hit the route? :)

Comment: Thank you for your reply, Marian.
1 - Duly noted!
2 - I don't understand where I can put the "from", the "to", the dynamic template ID. Do you know?
Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Twilio SendGrid developer evangelist here.

Check out [the documentation here that shows all the options you can use to send an email with the Ruby library](https://docs.sendgrid.com/api-reference/mail-send/mail-send?code-sample=code-v3-mail-send&code-language=Ruby&code-sdk-version=5.x) (excuse the use of `include`).

Based on the docs, here's a quick snippet that should cover your needs:

```rb
require 'sendgrid-ruby'

sg = SendGrid::API.new(api_key: ENV['SENDGRID_API_KEY'])
mail = SendGrid::Mail.new

mail.from = SendGrid::Email.new(email: "YOUR_FROM_ADDRESS")
mail.subject = "Your fancy, exciting subject line"
mail.template_id = "YOUR_TEMPLATE_ID"

personalization = SendGrid::Personalization.new
personalization.add_to(SendGridEmail.new(email: 'YOUR_CUSTOMER_EMAIL'))
personalization.add_dynamic_template_data({
  "name" => "example_name",
  "generation" => "dynamic"
})
mail.add_personalization(personalization)

sg.client.mail._("send").post(request_body: mail.to_json)
```

Take a look at [this specific example in the SendGrid Ruby library docs too](https://github.com/sendgrid/sendgrid-ruby/blob/main/use-cases/transactional-templates.md).